# How to delete multiple rows from JTable , database at a time

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I want to delete several rows from JTable at once but I'm only able to delete only one row at a time. Does JTable only allow one selection at a time? If I want to delete multiple rows by selecting them does java allow us to do so? The given code is only able to delete one row at a time even if I select multiple rows.

`DBConnection` is a  Class to connect to MySql Database.

`staffTable1` is a variable Name of `JTable`

`ShowStaffInStaffTable()` is a  Function to update my `JTable` rows and columns by importing data from MySql using Getter Setter Class

Here is my code that I have tried:

```
int row = staffTable1.getSelectedRow();
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) staffTable1.getModel();

String selected = model.getValueAt(row, 9).toString();

if (row >= 0) {
    try {
        DBConnection DB12 = new DBConnection();
        Connection conn = DB12.Connect();
        String sql = "delete from staff where Contact_No= ?";
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setString(1, selected);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        form12.ShowStaffInStaffTable();
    } catch (Exception w) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Connection Error!"+w);
        w.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: See [*How to Use Tables: User Selections*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection).

Comment: @trashgod I already know that we can select multiple rows from JTable by the methods that are in your specified link but my question is that how to delete multiple rows from JTable and database after selecting them? The given code (above) is only able to delete one row at a time even if I select multiple rows.

Comment: `multiple rows from JTable...after selecting` - `getSelectedRows` returns an array containing the indexes of the selected rows (current code posted uses `getSelectedRow`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following shows how to delete multiple selected rows from a JTable (and JList):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class ItemDeletion extends JPanel
{
    private JList<String> list;
    private JTable table;

    public ItemDeletion()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout(5, 5) );

        String[] items =
        {
            "One",
            "Two",
            "Three",
            "Four",
            "Five",
            "Six",
            "Seven",
            "Eight",
            "Nine",
            "Ten"
        };

        //  Add the list

        DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();

        for (String item: items)
            listModel.addElement( item );

        list = new JList<String>( listModel );


        JButton listDelete = new JButton( "Delete From List" );
        listDelete.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel)list.getModel();
                int row = list.getSelectedIndex();

                while (row != -1)
                {
                    model.removeElementAt( row );
                    row = list.getSelectedIndex();
                }
            }
        });

        JPanel listPanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout(5, 5) );
        listPanel.add(new JScrollPane( list ), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        listPanel.add(listDelete, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        //  Add the table

        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(0, 1);
        List<String> tableItems = Arrays.asList( items );
        Collections.shuffle( tableItems );

        for (String item: tableItems)
        {
            System.out.println( item );
            tableModel.addRow( new String[]{item} );
        }

        table = new JTable( tableModel );

        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        ((DefaultRowSorter)table.getRowSorter()).toggleSortOrder(0);

        JButton tableDelete = new JButton( "Delete From Table" );
        tableDelete.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
                int row = table.getSelectedRow();

                while (row != -1)
                {
                    int modelRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel( row );
                    model.removeRow( modelRow );
                    row = table.getSelectedRow();
                }
            }
        });

        JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout(5, 5) );
        tablePanel.add(new JScrollPane( table ), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        tablePanel.add(tableDelete, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        add(listPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        add(tablePanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Multiple Item Deletion");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new ItemDeletion(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Obviously you will need to modify the code to delete the row from the database as well.