# Final row in a Jtable can not be removed

Tags: java, swing, defaulttablemodel

I have the following code, that allows me to remove a row from the right Jtable with a click. It works fine for all the rows, except when there is only one row remaining. BTW, sorry for most names being in portuguese, its my native language. Here are the images showing before and after i click the final row in the table. It updates the total, but the row remains. For every other case, it works perfectly.

Screenshot:

[image]

```
private void jtbSelecionadosMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)                                             
{                                                 
    int x = jtbSelecionados.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
    if (x >= 0) 
    {
        String nomeProduto = (String)jtbSelecionados.getModel().getValueAt(x, 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < itensVenda.size();i++)
        {
            if (itensVenda.get(i).getNomeProduto().equals(nomeProduto))
            {
                if(itensVenda.get(i).getQtd() > 1)
                {


                    valorTotal -= (itensVenda.get(i).getPreco() / itensVenda.get(i).getQtd());
                    double precototal = itensVenda.get(i).getPreco();
                    double unit = precototal / itensVenda.get(i).getQtd();
                    System.out.println("Unidade: "+unit+"\nTotal: "+precototal);
                    itensVenda.get(i).setPreco(itensVenda.get(i).getPreco() - (itensVenda.get(i).getPreco() / itensVenda.get(i).getQtd()));
                    itensVenda.get(i).setQtd(itensVenda.get(i).getQtd() - 1);

                    recarregarTabela();
                }
                else if(itensVenda.get(i).getQtd() <= 1)
                {

                    valorTotal -= itensVenda.get(i).getPreco() / itensVenda.get(i).getQtd();


                    itensVenda.remove(i);
                    recarregarTabela(); 
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

function that resets the table with new information:

```
private void recarregarTabela()
{

    if (itensVenda.size() == 0)
    {   
        dtm.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
        dtm.setRowCount(0);
        lblTotal.setText("Total: R$" + String.valueOf(valorTotal));
    }
    else
    {

        dtm.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
        dtm.setRowCount(0);
        for (Item item : itensVenda)
        {

            Object[] vetor = new Object[3];
            vetor[0] = item.getNomeProduto();
            vetor[1] = item.getQtd();
            vetor[2] = String.format("%.2f", item.getPreco());
            System.out.println(item.getPreco());
            dtm.addRow(vetor);
        }
        lblTotal.setText("Total: R$" + String.valueOf(valorTotal));
    }
}
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227729/how-to-delete-multiple-rows-from-jtable-database-at-a-time/38228994#38228994 for an example that allows you to delete one (or more) selected rows.

Comment: I can delete rows, just not when there is only one row left

Comment: Then you can't delete rows!!! The last row is no different than the first row, except your logic is treating it differently, so fix your logic. You have been given a working example. Learn from the example.

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to rebuild whole model everytime a single row is deleted. As you already have index of clicked or selected row you can just remove it from model using `removeRow(index)` method. I suspect that `dtm` is a `DefaultTableModel` so just call `dtm.removeRow(index)` everytime you need to remove row from table

Comment: I tried that, and it works for everything, except when there is only one row, same as what i did =/

Comment: I changed it to the current way because that way wasnt working, but it turns out the other way doesnt work as well

Comment: @SalomãoAndrade: then you'll want to create and post a [mcve] with your question. Please read the link.

Comment: (1+) for suggestion the removeRow(...) method. @SalomãoAndrade, `I changed it to the current way because that way wasnt working,` - well that is the wrong approach. Removing a row from the `DefaultTableModel` is a single statement when you use the `removeRow(...)` method. I have no ideas why you would use anything else.

Comment: I tried something else because i thought there was something wrong with my approach, ill switch it back now

Comment: @SalomãoAndrade there is something wrong with your apporoach - not using model to change model content.

Comment: What do you mean?