# Removing selected JTable elements

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Several items in the table should be selected and erased when the button is pressed on ArrayList. But only one item is being deleted.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Table.getRowCount(); i++) {
            if (Table.isRowSelected(i)) {
               TableData.remove(i);
            }
}
Table.setModel(new DemoTableModel(TableData));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should NOT be removing data from the ArrayList.

The ArrayList can be used to load data into the `DefaultTableModel` but after you add the TableModel to the table all changes to the data should be done via the `DefaultTableModel`.

So in your case you would use:

```
model.removeRow(...)
```

method of the DefaultTableModel.

See: [How to delete multiple rows from JTable , database at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227729/how-to-delete-multiple-rows-from-jtable-database-at-a-time/38228994#38228994) for a working example that deletes all selected rows from the DefaultTableModel.

If you are using a custom TableModel, then the custom model should implement a `removeRow(...)` method. See [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for a step-by-step example that creates a custom TableModel using an ArrayList to hold the data. It show how to implement the "remove row" method.